# Using tee with bash hangs with some scripts

Tags: linux, bash, tee

I have a simple script file `startsql.sh` to start mysql:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to Start MySQL
echo "Starting MySQL"
if sudo service mysqld start; then
    echo "MySQL started successfully!"
else
    echo "Error: Failure to start MySQL" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I run it using:

```
bash startsql.sh |& tee -a scriptlogs.log
```

Though the service seems to start successfully, the command hangs after showing the messages on the command window. It works fine without hanging if I remove the tee. Interestingly I have a similar script to stop mysql and it works fine without issues. I checked and find no difference between the two scripts.

After searching a lot, I found that using the below works, but the side effect of this is that the tee process is still running in the background

```
bash startsql.sh > >( tee -a scriptlogs.log) 2>&1
```

Can someone please help me understand why does using tee hang on some occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Will you teach me the version of bash?
If you use bash 3.2.57, the error occure like this.

```
$ bash ./startsql.sh |& tee -a output.txt
bash ./startsql.sh |& tee -a output.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

Comment: The bash version is  4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Please note that if you are trying to reproduce the issue, you will have to stop mysql first and then run this script. It works fine if the mysql is already running. Thanks